# Javascript onclick html field value without editing .js file

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

```
<input type="text" 
       name='username'  
       onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Username';" 
       onfocus="if(this.value=='Username')this.value='';"
       value="Username" 
       class="register"/>
```

This is the code that I am using but the way my code is setup I want the text to be viewable in the field before the user types in their information but the way the form is setup now the

```
value="<?php echo $db_first_name; ?>"
```

but the code i'm using needs

```
value="Username"
```

to display username in the field before clicked by user and put in their own information.

I tried

```
value="Username<?php echo $db_first_name; ?>"
```

But obviously that did not work. Any Ideas?

Link to view functionality of form: http://odconnect.com/beta/registration2.php

Comment: Not sure if defining `name` twice was due to the edit or just from your code, but you should probably not define `name` twice.

Comment: Use this body tag: `<body onload="document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value='Username';">`

Comment: I'm not sure that's what you're trying to do, but I guess you should try this: `value=<?php echo $db_first_name == null ? "Username" : $db_first_name; ?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `placeholder` attribute (valid as of HTML5):

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?= $db_first_name; ?>" />
```

Alternatively (in other words, if you want to support users whose browsers don't support HTML5), you can test to see whether the user already has a username entered. If it's `null` or an empty string, set the value to "Username" otherwise, set the value to the value of `$db_first_name`. Then change the onBlur event to check for the length of the value of the field, and if the length is zero, have it display "Username". Finally, change the onFocus event to listen for a mouse-click - when the user gives focus to the field, set the value to an empty string.

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?= $db_first_name == "" ? "Username" : $db_first_name ?>" onBlur="checkUsernameBlur(this, 'Username');" onFocus="checkUsernameFocus(this, 'Username');" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript>
    function checkUsernameBlur(inputObj, label) {
        var strLen = inputObj.value.length;
        if (strLen == 0) {
            inputObj.value = label;
        }
    }

    function checkUsernameFocus(inputObj, label) {
        var value = inputObj.value;
        if (value == label) {
            inputObj.value = "";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Looks goo dman! I will accept as answer as soon as it lets me. Does this work in all browsers?

Comment: You're going to want to test. I just hacked this together in 2 minutes without testing it.

Comment: @BrandenBrown FYI, the functionality you linked to is from the `placeholder` attribute. No JS necessary. The only thing is that it won't work in older browsers that don't support HTML5.

Comment: Yes, you are right the placeholder attribute does not work in older browsers. So I have to add the javascript above for every single field?

Comment: Yeah. If you're using it for every field, though, I would add a second parameter for each function (`label`, for example) that would replace the use of "Username". I'll update my code.

Comment: I don't contact other users with my personal email address, and I don't want to set up a throwaway right now.

Answer (score -1):

To work in lower html versions not only in html5 change the **Username** text in all the three places to the wanted word or php variable

```
<input type="text"  name='username'  name='username' onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='<?php echo $db_first_name; ?>';" onfocus="if(this.value=='<?php echo $db_first_name; ?>')this.value='';" value="<?php echo $db_first_name; ?>" class="register"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't help OP. Take a look at the functionality he wants (linked in quesiton). This won't do that at all.

Comment: If you remove this answer, you'll regain any lost reputation points.